# Using ESP32 as a2dp sink and access point at the same time

Tags: microcontroller, bluetooth, wifi

I am trying to make a project where bluetooth and wifi collaborate with each other. Precisely I want to use the a2dp profile to stream the music to one esp, from there via UDP sockets to N esp's.

I am at a point where I thought I would be done, but when I try to send the received data from my phone over the socket, the access point is crashing. It seems like the whole resources are used to power the a2dp sink.

Does anyone has any ideas? Is this technically achieveable? If yes I surely have something in my code.

Appreciate any help.

Here's my code: https://github.com/Dimfred/esp32_bt_streamer

I am using the esp32-wroom btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found this post:

https://www.esp32.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=6707&start=30

It seems that a station and bluetooth can coexist ( tested it now have no problems ) but an access point and bluetooth is too much, since the wifi and bt module share one antenna.